# How do you make an background image have perspective zoom in html pages?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to make an image or background image have perspective zoom like iPhone wallpapers do for html pages?

Comment: Do you have a pic of what you're referring to?

Comment: When changing your iPhone wallpapers, there is an option for still photos called perspective zoom that slightly shifts the image in the opposite direction of the way you tilt your camera, I'm asking if theres a way to make an image on html do the same thing.

Comment: I don't have an iPhone so I don't know what you're referring to, but it sounds like you need to use the Gyroscope API and a CSS transform.

Comment: There is a css property called perspective. I don't know whether it will be helpful or not but you can check it out here. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/perspective

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/rotate3d()

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

create a css class:

```
.zoom {
    zoom: 2;
    -moz-transform: scale(2);
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

and then use javascript to toggle the class